# Android - Phone Table using contactscontract, pulls all records i need one i speify. 

Tags: java, android

When i use this code, it returns ALL records in phone table with name & number in my test Toast display.
ANY help or direction would be GREAT

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex    (ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
              if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                           null,
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                           new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     Toast.makeText(ZipCode.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);



                 }
                pCur.close();
```

My idea is to establish the 'id' string... but not sure where in code to do it.. and need help with protect string int or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update this line of code:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);
```

to take in a selection like the following:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[]{ id }, null);
```

This will only query for the contacts whose id is equal to the one specified. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes, and if you dont mind the string code to put my pre-defined ID in? maybe:  private static final int id = "1234" ?? sorry noob.. ?

Comment: Do you mean the code to convert an int to a String? One way to do that is String.valueOf(yourIntegerVariable)

Comment: You have to get the id from somewhere. You cannot use a random id. Maybe what you really want is a different selection where you're querying for something more specific like a person's name?

Comment: would this work? Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{ name }, null); ??